# Keychain Won't Remember Router Administrative Password

Tags: network, safari, password, keychain, router

macOS High Sierra, Safari 11.1.2, MacBook Air mid-2013, Netgear R6400 wifi router. All the software on the computer and router is up to date. Both the Mac and Safari work without difficulty.

The network works fine, the computer connects easily (either via wifi or Ethernet), and except for this one issue I can access the router's administrative web pages and change its settings without difficulty.

The issue is...Keychain won't remember the router's administrative password. The router's administrative login page has a box to check to "Remember this password," which I dutifully check. The password is remembered for a few minutes only, then I have to manually enter it again. It's a complicated password, and I'd be happy if Keychain remembered it, as it does for every other password I use.

I've quit and restarted Safari, deleted the Keychain entry for the router (and all other 192.xxx.x.x URLs, there weren't many), deleted Safari’s cache and cookies related to this URL, quit and restarted Keychain, restored the router .cfg file from backup, and restarted the computer in Safe Mode followed by deleting the Keychain entry again.

The forgetfulness continues. Any idea why this is happening? Anything else I might try to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The 'forgetfulness' is likely to be intentional.

Safari won't offer to remember any passwords etc if the page tells it not to.
I don't know the technical details of how this is accomplished, but banking pages etc won't do it either.
The 'remember' box on the page is not for Safari to remember, it's for the remote device.

There used to be a freeware extension called 'autocomplete' that would disable this [lack of] functionality in Safari, but it hasn't worked so well in recent years.
I just discovered the author now has a paid version, called [StopTheMadness](https://itunes.apple.com/app/stopthemadness/id1376402589?mt=12), still fully supported, which *might* do the same thing. I haven't been able to fully test it yet - just got it 5 minutes ago.

Comment: let me make it more complicated: I have the same model router (same firmware) at another location (our home) too, and *that* router's login info is seamlessly remembered on the iMac at my desk (same macOS as on the MacBook Air I travel with). The home router runs the same firmware as the router I wrote about, located tat our son's house. All of my various bank/money account passwords are remembered at home (the key symbol appears in the box, with no content - clicking fills in the info) but they're not autofilled without the clicking I just described.

Comment: The easiest workaround is login using Chrome, which happily remembers the password.

Comment: It'd still be interesting to know why the two apparently-identical systems behave differently.

Comment: Have you checked the keychain on both machines, see if you can see anything similar/different?

Comment: Good idea...*something's* got to be different. Will do so when I get back home on Sunday. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I finally had time to compare the Keychains for the two routers. The Keychain entries (there are two, both labeled "Internet Password") for the router-that-remembers are identical. However, one of the entries for the router-that-doesn't-remember had different content on its "Access Control" tab — the "always allow" box didn't contain "Safari" (as all the other entries did), but instead some other letters. I deleted that entry (so eager I was that I didn't take a screenshot), and will see what happens the next time I'm at the other location.